# Why do I get NameNotFound: Environment FrostbiteDeterministic doesn't exist, when using gym environments?

Tags: openai-gym

I am encountering the NameNotFound error, when I run the following code -

```
import gym
env = gym.make("FrostbiteDeterministic-v4")
observation, info = env.reset(seed=42, return_info=True)

for _ in range(1000):
    action = env.action_space.sample()
    observation, reward, done, info = env.step(action)

    if done:
        observation, info = env.reset(return_info=True)
env.close()
```

Here is the traceback -

```
NameNotFound                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [10], in <cell line: 2>()
      1 import gym
----> 2 env = gym.make("FrostbiteDeterministic-v4")
      3 observation, info = env.reset(seed=42, return_info=True)
      5 for _ in range(1000):

File ~\Anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\gym\envs\registration.py:578, in make(id, max_episode_steps, autoreset, disable_env_checker, **kwargs)
    572         logger.warn(
    573             f"Using the latest versioned environment `{new_env_id}` "
    574             f"instead of the unversioned environment `{id}`."
    575         )
    577     if spec_ is None:
--> 578         _check_version_exists(ns, name, version)
    579         raise error.Error(f"No registered env with id: {id}")
    581 _kwargs = spec_.kwargs.copy()

File ~\Anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\gym\envs\registration.py:209, in _check_version_exists(ns, name, version)
    206 if get_env_id(ns, name, version) in registry:
    207     return
--> 209 _check_name_exists(ns, name)
    210 if version is None:
    211     return

File ~\Anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\gym\envs\registration.py:187, in _check_name_exists(ns, name)
    184 namespace_msg = f" in namespace {ns}" if ns else ""
    185 suggestion_msg = f"Did you mean: `{suggestion[0]}`?" if suggestion else ""
--> 187 raise error.NameNotFound(
    188     f"Environment {name} doesn't exist{namespace_msg}. {suggestion_msg}"
    189 )

NameNotFound: Environment FrostbiteDeterministic doesn't exist.
```

I believe the environment should exist since people have used it over here - https://github.com/openai/gym/issues/1478
Perhaps it doesn't work with a later version of OpenAI gym?